# How to Deploy Inactive Duplicate and matching rule

Tags: deployment, ant, package, duplicate-management, data-migration

Before Data migration, we perform some pre-steps to migrate the data (data from source to destination Should be same)

Deactivating duplicate and matching Rules is one of the steps we perform as the pre-steps, we are trying to automate this step.

Is there any way we can **deploy the Inactive matching and duplicate rules in same package**?